# convert foreach into while loop

Tags: php, loops

Hi guys i need to convert a foreach loop into a while loop.
Because the foreach loop does leaves the block when values have been iterated. I need the while loop to continue looping.

I need to iterate the items of the array but not in a foreach loop.

```
foreach($values as $event) {
        if($startDate >= $event['start'] && $startDate <= $event['end']  ) {
            echo '<tr><td style="background:red;">Tijd: ' . strftime("== %H:%M ==", $startDate) . '<br/></td><td>'.$startDate.'</td></tr>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<tr><td style="background:green;">Tijd: ' . strftime("== %H:%M ==", $startDate) . '<br/></td><td>'.$startDate.'</td></tr>';
        }       
    }
```

My last post when into a disaster srry for that.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the foreach loop does leaves the block when values have been iterated".  A foreach loop iterates over each element once.  If you want to iterate multiple times, then put the foreach loop inside a for loop!

Comment: ^-- like Oli says.... Through what data are we looping if it has 'to continue looping' after the end is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to iterate through the array, this should do it:

```
$array_length = count($values);
$iteration    = 0;

while($iteration < $array_length){
    $event = $values[$iteration];
    ...
    $iteration++;
}
```

This functionality is much like a for() or foreach() loop, if you only want to exit the loop when a specific condition is met, you could do it like this:

```
$active = true;
$iteration = 0;

while($active){
    $event = $values[$iteration];
    ...
    if(some_condition){ $active = false; }
    $iteration++;
}
```

Note: You should put in some code which resets the iterator or sets $active to false if the iterator grows larger than or equal to the size of the values array, or else you will run into trouble